# How to elevate box with shadow?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have a Box comsopable I want to elevate with shadow

```
`Box(modifier = Modifier
            .sizeIn(100.dp)
            .background(Color.Magenta)) {
   Text("Lorem Ipsum")
}
```

How?

How to elevate box with shadow? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Modifier.shadow` before `Modifier.sizeIn`, it suffices shadow to be before `Modifier.background` to draw background over shadow but i have a habit of putting clip or shadow modifiers on top or start of Modifier chain. Order of shadow determines how it will be drawn.

[image]

```
@Composable
private fun ShadowSample(){
    Box(modifier = Modifier
        .sizeIn(100.dp)
        .background(Color.White)) {
        Text("Lorem Ipsum")
    }

    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))

    Box(modifier = Modifier
        .shadow(2.dp)
        .sizeIn(100.dp)
        .background(Color.White)) {
        Text("Lorem Ipsum")
    }

    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))

    Box(modifier = Modifier
        .shadow(8.dp)
        .sizeIn(100.dp)
        .background(Color.White)) {
        Text("Lorem Ipsum")
    }

    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))

    Box(modifier = Modifier
        .sizeIn(100.dp)
        .background(Color.White)
        .shadow(8.dp)
    ) {
        Text("Lorem Ipsum")
    }
}
```